# 404 error while refreshing using jsp servlets

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

Hi im new in jsp/servlets, i have a basic question about relative or abselute path:
i have the following hierarchy, using netbeans:

```
Web Pages
|  |-Status
|     |-clientRequests.jsp
|  |-index.jsp
|  |-WEB-INF
|     |-professional.jsp
```

`index.jsp` and the Status folder and  `WEB-INF` folder in root path.
inside the Status folder we have the `clientRequests.jsp` file.
inside the WEB-INF folder we have the `professional.jsp` file.

in the index.jsp i have done dispacher to `professional.jsp`,
inside professional jsp i have `<iframe src="Status/clientsRequests.jsp"></iframe>`
inside the `clientsRequests.jsp` i have

```
<%
        response.setHeader("Refresh", "5;url=../index.jsp");  
%>
```

that means that every 5 sec will be refresh to the `clientsRequests.jsp` file, and then go to the "controller" which is `index.jsp`.
now what i wanted to be that every 5 min, only the iframe refreshed and not the hole page.
my problem: in the **second** refresh it gives me 404.

i tried to play with that and i did something ugly like:

```
String a = (String)session.getAttribute("nav");
if(a == null){
    session.setAttribute("nav", "aaa");  
    response.setHeader("Refresh", "5;url=../index.jsp");  
}else{
    response.setHeader("Refresh", "5;url=index.jsp"); 
}
```

and its working, but i dont want wo leave that like this way...
do you have any suggestions?
thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Somehow your response is setting header for the parent of the iframe too. Put the below line in the  of clientsRequests.jsp.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
```

Comment: hey gaurav, but the problem with that it wont go to the "controller": index.jsp. with response.setHeader("Refresh", "5;url=../index.jsp"); it will

Comment: Then try some client side mechanism like : setTimeout or setInterval method. As setTimeout(function(){ document.frames["frameNameHere"].location = '/whatever path you want it to go to'; },5000);

Answer (score 1):

one Alternative would be to `move the clientRequests.jsp to the same level as index.jsp`.
That way in your code you can always do this

```
response.setHeader("Refresh", "5;url=index.jsp");
```

One advantage is with this set up , the `<iframe src="Status/clientsRequests.jsp"></iframe>` can be added to any of the JSP pages in your application and there is no change/impact in the servlet code